# Sending a PCIe message

Tags: pci-e

How to send a PCIe message(specifically VDMs - Vendor Defined Messages) from a host application/driver? Is there any windows API to do the same, like there are APIs for Memory R/W or I/O R/W ?

I could see Teledyne tool having support for PCIe VDM support, if anyone knows how this can be achieved, please clarify on the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware PCIe packet generators are available for generating custom PCIe packets. Not aware of anything equivalent in software.

Answer (score 0):

PCIe VDM packet can't be send from host's application/driver. There is hardware needed on PCIe Bus so that data VDM TLP packet could be generated and send the destination device.

E.g. Management controller on motherboard can send PCIe VDM packet to NVMe SSD device.

PCIe VDM Packet send from BMC to NVMe SSD:

[image: PCIe VDM Packet send from BMC to NVMe SSD]